# Are a FileInfo's Properties saved in memory?

Tags: c#, .net

When doing something like `... = myFileInfo.FullName` - does it access the drive or is it loaded to memory with the creation of myFileInfo?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, they are saved in memory - it's a snapshot of the file when you created the [FileInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx) class and ***first* accessed** a property. You can call the [Refresh](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.refresh.aspx) method to make sure the properties are up to date.

You can also use the static members of the [File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.aspx) class to read the file info at that point in time, however, this incurs the overhead of a security check each time.

My evidence for this comes from using [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/); we can see that, if we access a property like Length:

```
    public long Length
    {
        [SecuritySafeCritical]
        get
        {
            if (this._dataInitialised == -1)
            {
                base.Refresh();
            }
            if (this._dataInitialised != 0)
            {
                __Error.WinIOError(this._dataInitialised, base.DisplayPath);
            }
            if ((this._data.fileAttributes & 16) != 0)
            {
                __Error.WinIOError(2, base.DisplayPath);
            }
            return (long)this._data.fileSizeHigh << 32 | ((long)this._data.fileSizeLow & (long)((ulong)-1));
        }
    }
```

Then, if the internal data has not been initialized, Refresh is called:

```
public void Refresh()
{
    this._dataInitialised = File.FillAttributeInfo(this.FullPath, ref this._data, false, false);
}
```

This then populates the data for subsequent checks. So **unless** you call Refresh again, you'll get the data from the point in time you first accessed a property.

The reason for caching this data is inferred from the FileInfo MSDN article:

> If you are going to reuse an object several times, consider using the
>   instance method of FileInfo instead of the corresponding static
>   methods of the File class, because a security check will not always be
>   necessary.

It obviously caches this data to avoid the expense of a SecurityCheck each time, leaving it up to the user to call Refresh and decide when to pay this cost.

Comment: Additionally, there's a Refresh-method that clears the cache to ensure subsequent calls will get the data from the file system.